# Setting collection name in Firebase function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Just starting to use Firebase functions and have the sample working, but confused because the update event doesn't occur if I change the 'messages' collection to a different name, eg 'listings'. I change the word 'messages' in two places, on the 'add' and the 'makeUppercase' line. I get the response OK, it writes the data to the collection, but doesn't fire the event. Must be simple, but can't google it.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.addMessage = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    // Grab the location parameter.
    const inputcode = req.query.code || 'blank';

    // Push the new message into Cloud Firestore using the Firebase Admin SDK.
    const writeResult = await admin.firestore().collection('messages').add({inputcode: inputcode});
    // Send back a message that we've succesfully written the message
    res.json({result: `Message with ID: ${writeResult.id} added.`});
  });

exports.makeUppercase = functions.firestore.document('/messages/{documentId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
      // Grab the current value of what was written to Cloud Firestore.
      const inputcode = snap.data().inputcode;

      // Access the parameter `{documentId}` with `context.params`
      functions.logger.log('Uppercasing', context.params.documentId, inputcode);
      
      const areacode = inputcode.toUpperCase();
      const written = new Date();
      
      return snap.ref.set({written, areacode}, {merge: true});
    });
```

I'm using the local firebase emulator to do this test, by the way.

This is the new version, ony changing 'messages' to 'vvvv' in two places.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.addMessage = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    // Grab the location parameter.
    const inputcode = req.query.code || 'blank';

    // Push the new message into Cloud Firestore using the Firebase Admin SDK.
    const writeResult = await admin.firestore().collection('vvvvv').add({inputcode: inputcode});
    // Send back a message that we've succesfully written the message
    res.json({result: `Message with ID: ${writeResult.id} added.`});
  });

exports.makeUppercase = functions.firestore.document('/vvvvv/{documentId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
      // Grab the current value of what was written to Cloud Firestore.
      const inputcode = snap.data().inputcode;

      // Access the parameter `{documentId}` with `context.params`
      functions.logger.log('Uppercasing', context.params.documentId, inputcode);
      
      const areacode = inputcode.toUpperCase();
      const written = new Date();
      
      return snap.ref.set({written, areacode}, {merge: true});
    });
```

Comment: Are you saying the Firestore function doesn't trigger at all, and there's nothing in the functions log for that?  Are you sure function was deployed?

Comment: If I use the code as shown, the function is triggered. If I change the name 'messages' to 'views' for example, there is no event trigger. Nothing in the log except for Begin and FInshed of addMessage.

Comment: Why would you expect the function to run for documents in a different collection?  It's clearly set to recognize a specific path pattern. I suggest editing the question to be more clear about the specific situation that doesn't work the way you expect.  There should be enough information in the question so that anyone can duplicate the issue.

Comment: No, I'm just trying to set a different collection name. I expect the function to run because I'm doing the line,

```
firestore().collection('vvvvv').add
```
then listening for the event on 

```
functions.firestore.document('/vvvvv/{documentId}')
    .onCreate
```

All that I've changed is 'messages' => 'vvvvv'. The code above works, but I want to change the name 'messages'. Not sure how to explain that better.

Comment: OK, so, I suggest editing the question to show the new modified code that doesn't work the way you expect.  Be sure to deploy it before you test it.  Again we should be able to take the code out of your question and see for ourselves how it works.

Answer (score 1):

OK. Doug, your suggestion sank in after an hour or so! I've restarted everything and think that I understand. If I change the name in those two places, without restarting, the collection.add function takes place and I can see the record in the new collection, but the onCreate event didn't fire. I had to restart the whole service to restart buth parts. I was getting confused because one part was working and not the other. Thanks for your patience.